# shell_exec('hg clone http://localhost/hg/TestProject/')... Not working

Tags: php, macos, mercurial, terminal

Can someone let me know why I'm unable to clone local repos using the following code:

```
$output = shell_exec('hg clone http://localhost/hg/TestProject/');

echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

The output is "127". What's wrong? It's working perfectly through terminal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sh -c X` returns 127 when X does not exist. This probably means `hg` is not in the path when you execute the script. You could run `which hg` to find out what the full path is and supply that instead (mine is `/usr/bin/hg`), or you could set the PATH environment variable so that `hg` can be found.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that PHP can't find the hg executable.
Try to specify the full path to hg